# HTML onclick isn't running function

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript and just getting into it for my web design class. I am working on a project with Javascript inside HTML. I have it all written, but the HTML doesn't seem to call the Javascript function. I've been searching for a solution but can't seem to get anything to work. The code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var calculateInterest = function(){
var rate;
var total;
var years = document.getElementById("years").value;
var principleAmount = document.getElementById("principal").value;
var interestRate = document.getElementById("intrest").value;
    if ((interestRate >= 0) && (interestRate <= 15)) {
        rate = interestRate / 100;

        if ((principleAmount >= 0) && (principleAmount <= 10000)) {
            total = principleAmount * (1 + rate * years);
            document.getElementById("total_with_intrest").value = total;
        }
        else {
            message-box ("Invalid data for principle amount.");
        }
    }
    else {
        message-box ("Invalid data for interest rate.");
    }
}
</script>
<style>
form{ border: solid blue;
       width:40em;
        padding:0.5em;}
input{padding: 0.5em;}

</style>
</head>


<body>
<form>

Enter Principal Ammount : <input type="text" id ="principal"  />
</br>

Enter Intrest Rate : <input type="text" id ="intrest"    />
</br>
Enter Number of Years : <input type="text" id ="years"  />
</br>
Grand Ammount : <input type="text" id ="total_with_intrest"   disabled /></br>
</br>
<input type="button" id="click" value="Calculate" onclick=calculateInterest()/> </br>


</form>
</body>

</html>
```

The browser error is "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}' " on line 2 but I just can't see what the issue is. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Side note, I am aware there are some weird spelling mistakes. My instructor is from India and not totally fluent in English. She made the HTML file for us to use and we just have to put in the Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `message-box` function. Did you mean [`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)? Your code currently works, with those changes:

```js
var calculateInterest = function(){
    var rate;
    var total;
    var years = document.getElementById("years").value;
    var principleAmount = document.getElementById("principal").value;
    var interestRate = document.getElementById("intrest").value;
    if ((interestRate >= 0) && (interestRate <= 15)) {
        rate = interestRate / 100;

        if ((principleAmount >= 0) && (principleAmount <= 10000)) {
            total = principleAmount * (1 + rate * years);
            document.getElementById("total_with_intrest").value = total;
        }
        else {
            alert("Invalid data for principle amount.");
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Invalid data for interest rate.");
    }
}
```

```css
form{ border: solid blue;
       width:40em;
        padding:0.5em;}
input{padding: 0.5em;}
```

```html
<form>

Enter Principal Amount : <input type="text" id ="principal"  />
</br>

Enter Interest Rate : <input type="text" id ="intrest"    />
</br>
Enter Number of Years : <input type="text" id ="years"  />
</br>
Grand Amount : <input type="text" id ="total_with_intrest"   disabled /></br>
</br>
<input type="button" id="click" value="Calculate" onclick="calculateInterest()" /> </br>


</form>
```

Small Nitpick: Fixed some small typos not related to code. Ammount => Amount. Intrest => Interest.

Comment: I think you will find the function is called without the quotes

Comment: @Katie.Sun Yup, appears so. Updated my answer.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I couldn't remember exactly what it was and went to leave myself a comment to return to it and it auto populated with message-box so I thought it was correct.